# Where is the email client on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, email, outlook-express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Email Client For Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/189768/email-client-for-windows)

hi my dear friends :
i could n't find outllok express in windows 7 ...
for managing my emails what should i do ?

What are the best mail Managers for windows 7  = windows base?

thanks in future adveance
best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called mail client. I don't know about outlook-express, but for a free one, check [Mozilla Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/thunderbird).

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7, you can download and install the official [Windows Live Mail 2011](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mail?os=other).